# Deploy orange Model as web service

Tags: orange

I have created a model using Orange data mining that I am happy with.
I would like to use this model as a web service for real time categorization,
Is there an option to use this Orange flow as a Web Service using my trained model ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way you can deploy Orange workflows created through visual programming as web services.